# When does a new Content Type get crawled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I just created a new content type in Site Collection A.  I am running a query in Site Collection B via a Search Web Part that tries to pull back list items using this new content type via spcontenttype.  However 0 items are being returned.  I did click on re-index within Advanced properties of the list, but I still see nothing in my query.  I talked to my Site Collection admin and he said the continuous crawl is frequent and and the full crawl is on the week-end. He had no idea if this relates to my issue.

Is my issue related to the fact that the full crawl has not taken place.  My query is spcontenttype:newcontenttype WebID

When I run this query for other content types it returns items, thus the reason I thought it may have to do with the crawl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New content type, which contains new crawled properties, will be indexed in next Full Crawl.

Depends on your farm's size, full crawl could take a very long time. Also, in your case, if you find the search result is not working as expected, you need to wait for a week to debug.

It is suggested to test in your development farm before roll out to production. You can do full crawl anytime you wish. It is also what most SharePoint developers do.